# Two fields of two records have same label in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml, record

I have defined two record types:

```
type name =
    { r0: int; r1: int; c0: int; c1: int;
      typ: dtype;
      uid: uid (* key *) }

and func =
    { name: string;
      typ: dtype;
      params: var list;
      body: block }
```

And I have got an error later for a line of code: `Error: The record field label typ belongs to the type Syntax.func but is mixed here with labels of type Syntax.name`

Could anyone tell me if we should not have two fields of two records have same label, like `typ` here, which makes compiler confuse.

Comment: Update: since OCaml version 4.01.0 the requirement for unique record field labels is removed.

Comment: @Str. I think that is only true if the names have different types, which does not apply here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No you can't because it will break type inference.

btw, you can use module namespace to fix that:

```
module Name = struct
  type t = { r0:int; ... }
end

module Func = struct
  type t = { name: string; ... }
end
```

And then later, you can prefix the field name by the right module:

```
let get_type r = r.Name.typ
let name = { Name.r0=1; r1=2; ... }
let f = { Func.name="foo"; typ=...; ... }
```

Note that you need to prefix the first field only, and the compiler will understand automatically which type the value you are writing has.

Comment: Maybe you can add a link to the FAQ: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/FAQ_EXPERT-eng.html#labels_surcharge

Answer (score 8):

The Ocaml language requires all fields inside a module to have different names. Otherwise, it won't be able to infer the type of the below function

```
let get_typ r = r.typ ;;
```

because it could be of type `name -> dtype` or of type `func -> dtype`

BTW, I suggest you to have a suffix like `_t` for all your type names.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Why do you think it is better to have a suffix like `_t` for type names?

Comment: Just a question of readability. I feel that `dtype` sounds like some value (e.g. some function).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch seeing as type and value contexts are always known, surely there's no ambiguity?

Answer (score 1):

You can use type annotation in function signature when compiler failed to infer the type from the duplicate record label. For example,

```
let get_name_type (n:name) = n.typ

let get_func_type (f:func) = f.typ
```