# Record labels must be globally unique?

Tags: ocaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two fields of two records have same label in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928970/two-fields-of-two-records-have-same-label-in-ocaml)

In Ocaml 3.12.0, is it necessary that any labels of a record have globally unique names?

```
type foo = { a : int; b : char; }
# type bar = {a : int; b : string};;
type bar = { a : int; b : string; }
# {a=3; b='a'};;
  {a=3; b='a'};;
Error: This expression has type char but an expression was expected of type
         string
```

I guess if the record is created anonymously, the only way for the compiler to know which type I'm referring to is the record names. Does declaring `bar` hide `foo`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, record labels don't have to be globally unique. But they have to be unique in module level.

Declaring `bar` doesn't hide `foo`; therefore, type inference is broken when refering to `b` field.

You can easily create submodules and use module names to distinguish between records with the same label:

```
module Foo = struct
  type foo = {a: int; b: char}
end

module Bar = struct
  type bar = {a: int; b: string}
end

let f = {Foo.a = 3; b = 'a'} (* Note that we only need to use module name once *)
let b = {Bar.a = 3; b = "a"}
```

Comment: I didn't know that it is enough to use module name only once, thanks! For those who are interested, I wrote a camlp4-based [syntax extension](https://github.com/alavrik/piqi/tree/master/piqi-camlp4) that makes it a little bit prettier. Basically, it lets you write same thing like this: `Foo#{a = 3; b = 'a'}`. The difference is that it will work for all the nested Foo's as well.

Comment: `let open ... in` is also very handy in this context, e.g. one can write `let open Foo in let f = {a = 3; b = 'a'}`.

Comment: @AntonLavrik: Thanks for the tip about `open`. It's really helpful.

Comment: You can also use the Foo.(...) form of local module opening. This syntax can be helpful when trying to limit the scope of an open.